# ¿En qué afecta los modos de renderizado de Nuxt 3 en la ejecución de codigo?

Tags: vue3, nuxt

Presento el siguiente comportamiento

Supongamos que tengo un page donde se ejecuta varios life cycle hooks de vue como `onBeforeMount` y `onMounted` estos life cycles hooks ejectuan perfectamente cuando la page es accedida mediante `NuxtLink` o también el `useRouter` composable de Nuxt 3

pero cuando se accede mediante la URL del nevagador a la page esta se muestra como si fuese estatica totalmente, no ejecuta los life cycle hooks y tampoco creo que ejecuta algún otro codigo de js o ts. Yo a este problema lo solucioné cambiando las reglas de ruta en `nuxt.config.[ts, js]` de la siguiente manera

```
import { env } from "process";

// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    //...

    routeRules: {
        "/page": {
           ssr: false
        }
})
```

Entiendo que esto renderiza la page en solo `client side rendering` pero mi duda es ¿por defecto que tipo de renderizado toma nuxt? ¿Por qué pasa este comportamiento?